# Bash For Loop for RNAseq Alignment

Tags: bash, alignment, sequence, rna-seq

my mind simply does not work with for loops, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Background: I am trying my hand at analyzing some RNAseq data and need to write a for loop to read all my pair-ended fastq files through STAR.

This is the code I have right now:

```
#! /bin/bash

#PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=12
#PBS -l mem=48

# ENVIRONMENT
module load gcc/6.2.0
module load STAR/2.6.1d
prj=/gpfs/data/elf-lab/RNA_Seq/RNA_trial/sab_sandbox/

# INPUTS
sample=SE-QS-19-FC01_S*

staridx=${prj}/reference/hg38_gencode28_STAR

fq1=${prj}/data/${sample}.R1_001.fastq
fq2=${prj}/data/${sample}.R2_001.fastq

rgline="ID:${sample}    PU:${sample}    SM:${sample}    PL:ILLUMINA LB:${sample}"

# OUTPUTS
outprefix=${prj}/alignment/${sample}.

# COMMAND
STAR \
  --runThreadN 12 \
  --genomeDir $staridx \
  --readFilesIn $fq1 $fq2 \
  --outSAMtype BAM Unsorted \
  --outSAMunmapped Within \
  --outFileNamePrefix $outprefix \
  --outSAMattrRGline $rgline \
  --outSAMattributes NH HI AS nM NM \
  --quantMode GeneCounts
```

And here is what my files look like:

```
SE-QS-19-FC01_S33_R1_001.fastq.gz
SE-QS-19-FC01_S33_R2_001.fastq.gz
SE-QS-20-FC01_S34_R1_001.fastq.gz
SE-QS-20-FC01_S34_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I want to write a for loop so that fq1 and fq2 will be each pair for each read, but am not sure exactly where to place the for loop so that fq1 and fq2 can be used in the STAR command. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've looped through R1.fastq/R2.fastq files before using arrays, assuming you have an equal number of R1/R2 files, e.g.

```
#! /bin/bash

#PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=12
#PBS -l mem=48

# ENVIRONMENT
module load gcc/6.2.0
module load STAR/2.6.1d
prj=/gpfs/data/elf-lab/RNA_Seq/RNA_trial/sab_sandbox/

staridx=${prj}/reference/hg38_gencode28_STAR

## Make arrays named fq1 and fq2 ##
fq1=(${prj}/data/*.R1_001.fastq)
fq2=(${prj}/data/*.R2_001.fastq)

# COMMAND
for ((i=0;i<"${#fq1[@]}";i++)); do
  sample="${fq1[$i]%%_R*}"
  rgline="ID:${sample}    PU:${sample}    SM:${sample}    PL:ILLUMINA LB:${sample}"
  outprefix=${prj}/alignment/"${sample}"

  STAR \
  --runThreadN 12 \
  --genomeDir $staridx \
  --readFilesIn "${fq1[$i]}" "${fq2[$i]}" \
  --outSAMtype BAM Unsorted \
  --outSAMunmapped Within \
  --outFileNamePrefix $outprefix \
  --outSAMattrRGline $rgline \
  --outSAMattributes NH HI AS nM NM \
  --quantMode GeneCounts
done
```

You also might want to add `--readFilesCommand gunzip -c` if your files are gzipped (like in your example) per https://www.biostars.org/p/243683/.

Further explanation of this c-style for-loop here: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-for-loop/#the-c-style-bash-for-loop

Hope this helps - there are a number of ways to solve this problem - if you want more help, add more details to your question e.g. include the code you've used that hasn't worked.

Comment: hi. I wrote a small bash library for doing a couple of things like this more easily. checkout https://github.com/koriege/bashbone especially `alignment::star` function.

Comment: Hi @jared_mamrot thank you so much! I guess I am realizing I may also need a loop to create the appropriate `${sample}` name since my samples only have in common the `SE-QS-` portion and are then tagged by the sample number, here 19 and 20, and then each has their respective pairs R1 and R2. Or does your code account for this?

Comment: If you bring `"${sample}"` into the loop it should solve the issue - I've updated my answer to use everything before _R1 / _R2 as the sample ID (e.g. `SE-QS-19-FC01_S33_R1_001.fastq.gz` becomes `SE-QS-19-FC01_S33`). Is this what you are trying to do?